# How to explain to a non-statistician researcher why the 2-sample Hodges-Lehmann-estimator is reported instead of the difference in median?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, median, hypothesis-testing

I need to explain the result of the wilcox.test in R. Many people believe it's about medians. Of course it is not. I understand this is a useful non-parametric measure about statistical equality of two samples, but how to explain this to a person asks me about medians? It's easy to find examples, where the "shift location" in wilcox.test is very different than difference in medians, even changes the sign.

I have a ridiculous situation, when median(A) - median(B) = 0.25, while the pseudomedian for A and B = -0.5. Intuitively, I would like to report medians, but the test shows completely opposite direction.

I know the pseudomedian approaches median as the distribution gets symmetric, but I have very skewed ones, so it won't work at all.

Actually, I have never seen any test of medians. Why? How to explain to a research, "Sir, I report the estimator of pseudomedian, because......."

Comment: You may find [this article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200202) answers some of your questions (though it is written for users of Stata).

Comment: When you say wilcox.test do you mean the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney rank sum test? What do you mean by stating that the test shows completely opposite direction?

Comment: If the data is very skewed then the Wilcoxon test might be a bad choice. It is for non-normal but still sort of symmetrical data. You might want to look into other non parametric tests such as the Brunner Munzel, which does not use an estimator of central location at all.